# for...of statement in js - issue with dom collection

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn ES2015 and i am having issue with the small function that i have to parse some DOM element and to find all textnodes and delete them.

And I have this function in simple for loop statement.

```
    function deleteTextNodes(element) {
    if(!element) {
        throw new Error ("Element doesn't exist")
    }
for (let i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i ++) {
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[i]);
        i--;
    } else if(element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
        deleteTextNodes(element.childNodes[i])
    }
}
```

And my try to rewrite function in for...on statement syntax below

```
function deleteTextNodes(element) {
if(!element) {
    throw new Error ("Element doesn't exist")
}
for( elem of element.childNodes ) {
    console.log(elem, elem.nodeType, );
    if (elem.nodeType == 3) {
        element.removeChild(elem);
    } else if(elem.nodeType == 1) {
        deleteTextNodes(elem)
    }
}
return true
```

}

Probably, second function works fine except one - for...on jump over next one node after deletes textnode or something like this. I fix this issue in, first function by adding `i--;`

So, the question is how to fix this issue in second function?

Comment: try `Array.from(element.childNodes)`

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Thx U, it works!

Comment: What does *probably* mean? Have you tried it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an alternative suggestion, since the scope is playing around with ES6:

```
function deleteTextNodes(element) {
  if(!element) {
      throw new Error ("Element doesn't exist")
  }
  let coll = [element];
  while(coll.length){
    [{nodeType:nt}] = ([element,...coll] = coll);
    if (nt == 3) {
        element.remove();
    } else if(nt == 1) {
        coll.push(...element.childNodes);
    }
  }
}
```

This prevents the need for recursion by continuously adding the childnodes to the collection. `[element,...coll] = coll` assigns the first element to the element var and assigns the remaining collection to coll.
Not necessarily better, but it shows some nice elements of destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteTextNodes(element) {
  if (!element) {
    throw new Error("Element doesn't exist")
  }
  let removeElement = [];
  for (elem of element.childNodes) {
    if (elem.nodeType == 3) {
      removeElement.push(elem);
    } else if (elem.nodeType == 1) {
      deleteTextNodes(elem)
    }
  }
  removeElement.forEach(elem =>elem.remove());
  return true
}
```